# Why object can be sometimes invisible in new session?

Tags: hibernate, grails, persistence, grails-orm

Consider the piece of code below.

Sometimes it happens to me that I see ???. But most of the time this works. Could someone please explain why this could happen and how can I make it work always?

I'm seeing this with Grails 2.2.4 & Mysql 5.5

```
domain.save(flush: true)
Domain.withNewSession {
  domain = Domain.get(domain.id)
  if (!domain)
    println "???"
}
```

Comment: Validation error sometimes?

Comment: Pretty sure no (I'm testing same data all the time)

Comment: Can you check if `Thread.sleep()` after flush removes the issue?

Comment: Why do you want to start a new session?

Comment: I have a quartz job that does some processing in a loop. It happens that if some iteration fails, current hibernate session gets broken or closed, so subsequent iterations also fail, for example with LazyInitializationException. So I'm putting every iteration in own new session.